# how to know the height of a control? I get NaN

Tags: c#-4.0, printing, wpf-4.0

I have an application that use the MVVM pattern. In the main view model, I create a view and its viewmodel of another control.

I need to know the height of the control, but when I create the control, if I see the Height value of the control I get NaN.

I use this code in my main view model:

```
miSecondControl = new mySecondControl(param1, param2);

double myHeight = miSecondControl.height;
```

This secondary control does not use the MVVM patter but it has code behind, because I only want to use it to print a fixed document, so I think that in this case MVVM would make more complex the solution.

I need the heigh property of the control to know if I need to create a new page because I don't have space in the actual page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Height/Width are values that are specified at design/layout time.

Use [FrameworkElement.ActualHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx) and [FrameworkElement.ActualWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx) to get the **rendered** Height/Width of a control.

Comment: ActualHeight is 0.0 in my case. Is not updated until I show the dialog. I need to know the height before show the window.

Comment: How can you know the width/height of your control if it is hidden ?

Comment: Yes, but if created the control but still I don not show, I thoguht that this values are avaliable.